# MIgrate primary key LOB columns - CDC phase

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I'm trying to do a full load + CDC replication from an RDS instance (postgres 11) to an RDS cluster (Aurora Postgres 11).
Some of the tables in my database have `text` columns as primary keys (which are considered LOBs).

During the full load phase, these columns are migrated inline (by configuring the `InlineLobMaxSize` parameter). But according to [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.TargetMetadata.html),

> InlineLobMaxSize – This value determines which LOBs AWS DMS transfers inline during a **full load**.

Which causes the migration to fail during the CDC phase, with errors like

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "xxx_pkey"
>
> DETAIL: Key (xxx_id)=() already exists.

Seems like during CDC phase, it does the 2-step migration:

- Copies the row with a `null` value for the LOB column
- Copies the value itself.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is a lot of conjecture in your question. Note that "large object" in PostgreSQL is something quite different from `text`.

Comment: From what I understood, DMS treats `text` columns as LOBs (CLOBs actually), isn't that correct?

Comment: That may well be, and I don't know DMS. My comment just tried to caution you against possible misunderstandings, for example when you consult the PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: Did you try the FullLobMode setting? That looks like it will be more careful about transferring the entire LOB value in one shot, even if that's slower. (I haven't tried it myself.)